# limit distribution of weak convergent sequence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_n(t) \mid t \in T\}$ be a bounded stochastic proces for some non-empty set $T$, we assume that the finite dimensional distributions converge in distribution and we let for $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $t_1,\dots,t_k \in T$ distinct:
$$ \mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k} := \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}_{(X_n(t_1),\dots,X_n(t_k))} $$
where this limit is a weakly convergence limit.
Now I would like to prove that the collection $\{\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k} \mid t_1,\dots,t_k \in T \mbox{ distinct}\}$ satisfy the Kolmogorov properties, i.e.:

(C1) For $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and a one-to-one mapping $s:\{1,\dots,k\} \rightarrow \{1,\dots,k\}$, Borel measurable sets $H_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and distinct $t_1,\dots,t_k \in T$:
$$ \mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(H_1\times \dots \times H_k) = \mu_{t_{s(1)},\dots,t_{s(k)}}(H_{s(1)}\times \dots \times H_{s(k)}) $$

(C2) For the same $t_i$ and $H_i$:
$$\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(H_1\times \dots \times H_{k-1} \times \mathbb{R}) = \mu_{t_1,\dots,t_{k-1}} (H_1\times \dots \times H_{k-1}) $$

My own idea:

due to the Portmanteau theorem we know that if $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is Borel measurable and $\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(\delta B) = 0$ we have that $ \mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(B) := \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}_{(X_n(t_1),\dots,X_n(t_k))}(B) $ and it is easy to see that (C1) and (C2) hold for $\mathbb{P}_{(X_n(t_1),\dots,X_n(t_k))}$ so we can conclude that (C1) and (C2) hold for sets $H_1,\dots H_k$ with $\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(\delta(H_1\times\dots\times H_k) ) = \mu_{t_{s(1)},\dots,t_{s(k)}}(\delta(H_{s(1)}\times \dots \times H_{s(k)})) = \mu_{t_1,\dots,t_k}(\delta(H_1\times \dots \times H_{k-1} \times \mathbb{R}))=\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_{k-1}} (\delta(H_1\times \dots \times H_{k-1}))=0 $

but for the other cases I don't see a way to prove it. It should be something easy because it's not an exercise, it's just needed for a step in a proof I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Why did I get a -1?

Comment: I don't know why, maybe they missed your own idea being there and thought it was a homework dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ that coincide on sets of $(\mu+\nu)$-zero boundary. Denote $A_r=\{\prod (a_i-r,b_i+r)\}$, they are all disjoint and measurable, so $(\mu+\nu)(\partial A_r)$ cannot be non-zero for more than countable number of $r$. Choosing $r_n\downarrow 0$ such that $\mu(\partial A_{r_n})=\nu(\partial A_{r_n})=0$, we have that 
$$\mu(\{\prod [a_i,b_i]\})=\lim \mu(A_{r_n})=\nu(\{\prod [a_i,b_i]\}).$$ 
Taking monotone limits, we have that the measures coincide on the algebra generated by all cubes. Now, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra being generated by cubes, by the uniqueness of the extension of a measure from an algebra, our measures coincide everywhere.

Alternatively, one could take limits of the integrals from continuous functions to get that the weak limits coincide on all continuous functions and thus they are equal.